# Is this set S a subspace of a vector space of a real value function?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So I have been working around this exercise but don't know where to start with. It would be helpful to get some hints.

> $V$ is a subspace of a real value function. $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Is the set $S = \{ f(x) \mid f(32) = f(99) \}$ a subspace of $V$?

Comment: You want to show that $S$ is/is not a linear subspace of $V$, so it is probably best to first look at the definition of a linear subspace.

Comment: $S$ looks ill-defined. You probably mean just $f$ instead of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think together. What is the definition of a subspace? Three points come to mind:

1) The $0$ vector is in the space.

2) If any two vectors are in the space, so is their sum.

3) If a vector is in the space, so is any scalar multiple of it.

So, let us check the conditions one by one.

1) The $f(x) \equiv 0$ function sends all real numbers to $0$. Hence, it also sends $32$ and $99$ to $0$. Hence, $f(32) = f(99)=0$, so $0$ is part of the subset.

2) Suppose $f$ and $g$ are  two functions  such that $f(32)=f(99)$ and $g(32)=g(99)$. Note that:
$$
(f+g)(32) = f(32) + g(32) = f(99) + g(99) = (f+g)(99)
$$
So $(f+g)$ is also a part of the subset.

3) Suppose that $f$ is a function such that $f(32) = f(99)$. Multiplying $f$ by a non-zero scalar $c$, gives the function $(cf)(x) = c\cdot f(x)$. Note that:
$$
(cf)(32) = c \cdot f(32) = c \cdot f(99) = (cd)(99)
$$ 
Thus we have that $cf$ is also a part of the subset.

Since conditions $1,2,3$ have been satisfied by the subset $S$, it qualifies to be a subspace of the vector space of all real functions.

Comment: Thanks for the throughout explanation! This is very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome, @L.Towson